# Google App Engine: Cloud SQL could create instance because billing is not enabled

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to create a new instance: "Could not create an instance because billing is not enabled".
I can confirm billing is enabled.
Project number: 789994970901

Comment: Hi Esato: Can you please double-check your billing details, this happens when the project doesn't have an associated billing method. If you're still having trouble, please email cloud-sql@google.com and I'll try to help.

Comment: My project did indeed have an associated billing method. Apparently the problem happened because I was logged on to two google accounts at the same time on the same browser. I opened up another browser and, having logged on to a single account, I was able to create a Cloud SQL instance.